# error with elif. says that elif is a syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement

```
diamondCave = random.randint(1, 3)
    goldCave = random.randint(1, 3)
    while diamondCave == goldCave:
        goldCave = random.randint(1, 3)

    if chosenCave == str(diamondCave):
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
    print('full of diamonds!')
elif: chosenCave == str(goldCave):
    print('full of gold!')
else:
        print('hungry and gobbles you down in one bite!')
playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':

    displayIntro ()

    caveNumber = chooseCave()

    checkCave(caveNumber)

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
else:
        pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

I want to make the code so that each time a chest is picked, it plays a sound. When a diamond gets picked it makes a cool sound, when gold is picked, a different sound is played, and when the chest eats you, it should make a game over sound. Every time I use the code of the sound, it says that the elif statement is invalid syntax. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have an extraneous : after elif. It should be `elif chosenCave == str(goldCave):`. Also, I'm assuming that your indents are actually correct in the real script.

Comment: On the indents, one common reason the code might look right in your editor, but look wrong when pasted on SO, is that you're mixing tabs and spaces. That can also cause Python to misunderstand your indentation and give you errors—or, worse, run but not do what you expected—without anything visibly wrong to your eyes. If this is the problem, change your editor configuration, or get a different editor, so that it turns all tabs into spaces.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `elif:` is a syntax error.

The whole point of `elif` is that it means `else if`. Just like you can't write `if:` without a condition, you can't write `elif:` without a condition.

Meanwhile, the statement after the `:` is clearly supposed to be the condition expression, not a statement. So you almost certainly wanted this:

```
elif chosenCave == str(goldCave):
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ":" after the elif

```
elif: chosenCave == str(goldCave):
```

Like this:

```
elif chosenCave == str(goldCave):
```